# Compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin (n {\pi} {\sqrt[3] {n^{3} + 3n^{2} + 4n - 5}})$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I evaluate the limit?

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin (n {\pi} {\sqrt[3] {n^{3} + 3n^{2} + 4n - 5}})$$

I think the limit is $0$ but I fail to work it out properly. Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $\pie$ supposed to be $\pi$ or $\pi\cdot e$?

Comment: $\sqrt[3] {n^{3} + 3n^{2} + 4n - 5}\to n+1$ as $n\to\infty$. Note $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is a continues function, thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(...)=\sin (\lim_{n\to\infty} ...) $$

Comment: How can I show this?

Comment: $$\sqrt[3] {n^{3} + 3n^{2} + 4n - 5}=\sqrt[3] {(n+1)^3+n-6}=(n+1)\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{n-6}{(n+1)^3}}$$

Comment: i.e. according to your comment the limit becomes
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin (n(n + 1) {\pi})$$
which is simply $0$.

Comment: Is this over $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I see this question is marked as a duplicate, I do not agree with that. The question is similar, and so is the resolution method. But the answer is different. Moreover, the arguments used in answers of $\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}$ do not detail why this $\varepsilon_n\to 0$. And in this precise case, the Taylor expansion shows that a constant term in $\frac{1}{3}$ appears, it is not just $0$ as in the other problem ! The comments I see about continuity of sinus seem to obliviate that the real issue is about what's inside the sinus and the absolute need of Taylor expanding the cubic root.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$\sin(n^2\pi\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{4}{n^2}-\frac{5}{n^3}})$ and use Taylor expansion of the cubic root.

Solution : $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ because of parity ;-)

Comment: What do you mean with DL ?

Comment: Typo, I corrected. DL=sorry french acronym for Taylor developpement.

Comment: Yes, your answers sound very French

Answer (score 1):

To be as exact as possible, do not use that some limit is $n+1$, but use the difference to that sequence:

$$
\sin(n\pi(n+1+ε_n))=(-1)^{n(n+1)}\sin(n\pi\varepsilon_n)
$$
with
\begin{align}
ε_n&=\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n^2+4n-5}-(n+1)
\\
&=(n+1)\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{n-6}{(n+1)^3}}-1\right)
\\
&=\frac1{3(n+1)}+O\left(\frac1{(n+1)^2}\right)
\end{align}
As $n(n+1)$ is always even and $nε_n\to\frac13$, the sequence converges towards $\sin(\frac\pi3)$

Comment: According to my calculation ${n \epsilon_{n}} \rightarrow \frac {-5} {3}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.But the limit is same which is $\frac {\sqrt 3} {2}$.

Comment: I do not see how that is possible based on the above computation. As the difference is -2 or $-2\pi$ in the sine argument, it does indeed make no difference. $-$ But note that there was an error in the power of $(n+1)$ in the second cube root. The last line remains the same as $(n+1)·\frac13·\frac{n-6}{(n+1)^3}=\frac1{3(n+1)}-\frac{7}{3(n+1)^2}$.